# Is there a need for a reporting system in PHP?

Tags: php, open-source, reporting, report-generation

I have designed a reporting system to be used in our enterprise level application.
I am able to open source it as this is not our business, and we can gain improved code by contributing it to the community.
My question, is there all ready a reporting system written in PHP, written for php 5.3 by the latest standards etc?

Some features of the current version:

1. 100% MVC separation
2. Good framework to manipulate query results, before, during and after fetching
3. easily apply pagination to report
4. Extremely easy to apply numerous filters to reports
5. System, once is learned, can be easily extended (has hookups almost to anything)
6. easily re factored
7. statistical functionality.

(Will also be happy to hear what other features I need to add).

Comment: Did you ever open source this? The correct answer would be that there is a massive need for exactly this.

Comment: not yet, it is not ready, in my mind, as a standalone product. Working towards it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd be happy to check it out if you have a public repository (I'd be happier if its an hg repository)...

Now for your question:

There is no reason to not open source your project, even if there's a similar established project out there (which I don't know about and can't safely comment on). You shouldn't really care if there's something similar, since you've already built it and it's functional (assumptions based on the fact that your company already uses it or plans to use it in the very near future?). You should have looked at other projects *before* you go built your own, which I assume you did and didn't find something that covered all your needs.

As for the features:

If you're really set on open sourcing the project, don't add any new features and concentrate on documenting everything you already have. Give us user guides, dev guides, architectural documents and anything else you can possibly give. Features can wait, since you already have a nice set of core functionality.